# jQuery selector and traversing question

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery and the HTML below, can someone please suggest what's the best (ie. most efficient) way to retrieve **span.street_address_display** from **$("input")**. Thanks.

```
<tr>
<th class="address_name" scope="row">Work</th>
<td class="address_entry">
  <span class="street_address_display">123456 ABC Street</span> 
  <span class="city_display">Vancouver</span>,  
  <span class="state_province_display">British Columbia</span>  
  <span class="country_display">Canada</span>   
  <span class="post_code_display">V1A2B3</span> 
</td>
<td class="address_select"><input value="address_2" name="address_select" type="radio" /></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Efficient in terms of the complexity of the code, or in the execution?

Comment: huh? you want to retrieve a span from a radio?

Comment: Assuming one entry per `<tr>`: `$("input").parents("tr").find(".street_address_display");`

Comment: @Trey: A common request, if you have a `.click()` or `.change()` event on the radio.

Comment: @Orbling but you assume only one entry in which case you have a span... not a user editable text area or input, you are trying to get the inner html of? if there is only one, you have a single static value... why would you use javascript to dynamically grab the inner html?

Comment: @Orbling, in terms of the execution.

Comment: @Trey: The OP said nothing about grabbing the innerHTML, they might wish to highlight the element, or do any number of things to it.

Comment: so my first statement stands... it was a vague question, that is what my point was... does he have the input element in a function already? is this for an event? is this on page load? is he adding a description to the radio? efficiency depends a great deal on knowing what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: @ahmoo: See the answers below, the fragile ones that are based on just moving about in the DOM, without selectors, are the quickest.  But rely on the *exact* position of the elements relative to each other.

Comment: @Trey: Generally, I would agree, but the OP states clearly that he just wants to retrieve a given element relative to others.  In the context, it is obvious he means a jQuery object of the target element.  The efficiency of that is not related to purpose, but is to the stability of the HTML presented.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the tradeoff, @Orbling. And you are also right that I am just concerning with the traversing and not the purpose. The html is just a made up example to demonstrate my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're calling it within a function that has `this` being scoped to the input (otherwise you need to replace `this` with something that grabs the input), something like

`$(this).parent().prev().children('span.street_address_display')`

should take you to the span. As far as efficiency, I'd say the biggest place you'll notice differences will be something like IE, or places that can't grab by Tag or Class.

Mind you, this is doing direct lookups, so one level up with `.parent()` rather than going up until you find a `td`, the previous `td` and then only direct children of that `td` that are `span` and have the class `street_address_display`. This won't scrape deeply, so you're losing flexibility, but less look ups translates to faster. It's up to you if it's worth it.

Comment: Certainly fragile, but quick.

Answer (score 3):

```
var $input = $('input');
var street_address_display = $input.closest('td').prev().find('span.street_address_display');
```

or, if there are no other such spans in the table row,

```
var street_address_display = $input.closest('tr').find('span.street_address_display');
```

Answer (score 2):

You could simply do this as well:

```
$(".street_address_display",$("input").parents("tr"));
```

Note that it will only give you one result, so if you got multiple inputs, you need to define which one you are after, unless you can just use `this`.

For example:

```
$(".street_address_display",$("input:first").parents("tr"))
```

or

```
$(".street_address_display",$(this).parents("tr"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure if you looking to get the value of the input, the value of class "street_address_display" but this would work for each respectively:

```
 $('.street_address_display').html();


 $('input').val();
```

Comment: the question is more about the traversing but thanks anyways.

Comment: Good catch, fixed to class indicator, traversing is slow, directly queries to elements is much faster, you could additionally assign ids to each element and access as well, still faster (more efficient) than traversing backwards.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
var $my_span = $('input[name="address_select"]').parent().prev().children().first()
```

Comment: Exceptionally fragile, but probably the quickest, particularly if that initial input is via `$(this)`.

Comment: Yes @Orbling, I find traversing to be generally fragile and make attempts to avoid where possible.

Comment: If I have need of traversal, I always do it via classes, never via exact positioning, far too fragile - particularly as in my case, as in many companies, the HTML is not produced by the same person as the JS.